# Epsilon-delta proof for $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[f(x)^2\right]=L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

As the title suggests, I'm looking for help with how to formulate an epsilon-delta proof for the square of a limit. That is,

> Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[f(x)^2\right]=L^2$ using the precise definition of a limit.

I know an easy proof using the product rule,

Suppose $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[f(x)\right]=L$ then

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[f(x)^2\right]=\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[f(x)f(x)\right]=\lim\limits_{x \to a}\left[f(x)\right]\cdot\lim\limits_{x \to a} \left[f(x)\right]=L\cdot L=L^2$

But I am required to  know how to perform the proof using epsilon-delta. I know the precise definiton of a limit but I'm quite horrendous at applying it. Could I recieve some guidance on how to set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $L\neq 0$. (I will leave the case $L=0$ for you). Let $\epsilon>0$. As $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Hence whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$,

$|f(x)^2-L^2|=|f(x)-L||f(x)+L|=$

$|f(x)-L||f(x)-L+L+L|\leq|f(x)-L|(|f(x)-L|+2|L|)<\epsilon(\epsilon+2|L|)$

Comment: Then conclusion would be, $|f(x)^2-L^2|<\epsilon(\epsilon+2|L|)$ correct? So the distance between $f(x)^2$ and $L^2$ is less than the double the value of L added to and scaled by some epsilon? How does this statement prove the limit exists?

Comment: Recall that question, I realized the logic as I considered epsilon tending to zero. The function $f(x)^2$ is always within at least double the distance of L as we choose smaller and smaller epsilon values.